# Fakes Shim Generic Repository <object> not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, microsoft-fakes

```
    List<Customer> customerList= new List<Customer>();
    List<Employee> employeeList= new List<Employee>();

Fakes.ShimDataServiceRepository<object>.AllInstances.GetEntitiesExpressionOfFuncOfT0Boolean = (instance, filter) =>
    {     
           if (filter.Body.ToString().Contains("sg.CustomerName"))
                 {
                     return customerList.AsQueryable();
                 }
                 else if (filter.Body.ToString().Contains("ib.EmployeeName"))
                 {
                     return employeeList.AsQueryable();
                 }

         return null;
    };
```

When my test method call a business layer method and business layer method call unitofwork.CustomerRespository.GetEntities(filter condition) the call goes to

```
this.GetEntityQuery(filter, orderBy, includeProperties, startPage, pageSize);
```

and it inturn calls the actual database call and error.

The call is not hitting the point in the fake

```
return customerList.AsQueryable();
```

When i use the specific class 'Customer' instead of object like

```
`Fakes.ShimDataServiceRepository<Customer>`
```

it is working fine. But i need a general fake method. 
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Each instance of a generic class is a separate .NET type. Fakes API requires you to shim each instance individually and does not offer a single API to shim multiple types at this time.